# Clearing Wicket "Cache"/"Context" - Reloading Spring Context in Wicket

Tags: java, spring, wicket

I have a wicket web application which mounts a page, allowing users to choose what "mode" the application should start in, i.e. mock for development purposes and production for testing/QA/prod environments. Obviously this is only a feature that will be used for development purposes. Anyways, the mounted page simply presents the users with 2 choices in the form of a radio button. The back-end code reloads the Spring Application Context completely, allowing us to choose a different set of beans as per our needs. For example, when choosing the mock spring profile, we lack a lot of security and cache beans.

This seems to work fine, however the problem seems to be that, while Spring reloads without any issues, Wicket does not. It caches the old beans somehow so that the following happens. First, consider this piece of testcode:

```
public class MyPage extends Page {
  @Inject
  MyBean myBean;

public MyPage() {
  super("id");
  myBean.getData();
}
```

The two available sets of Springbeans both declare MyBean: mock returns static data when getData is called whereas production forwards the call to a WebService endpoint, does some filtering etc.

What happens is as follows: if the application starts and you choose mock profile from the radio-button-page, the mock data is read. However, going back to the radio-button-page and choosing the production profile shows us the problem:

```
WebApplication.get().getApplicationContext().getBean("myBean"); //returns the production instance
//Debugging the myBean instance in myPage shows it to be the mock instance
```

So, despite Spring refreshing fine, deleting old beans and creating a new set, Wicket uses the old bean version. How do we work around this? The two options we`ve considered are as follows:

- Refresh "everything in wicket". Unsure about how we'd go about this as I don't understand its magic all that well. In principle, what we'd want to do is WebApplication.get().refreshApplicationContext() or Session.clean() or something like that but nothing we've tried so far seems to work.
- Restarting the entire WebApplication, for example using an environment propery as a work-around. The problem with this approach is restarting the application programmatically without knowing what server we`re running on, i.e. we want it to work locally where we run Jetty and in development environments where the application runs on JBoss.

Any and all ideas are very welcome :)

Comment: The "problem" appears to be this class: http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/spring/injection/annot/AnnotProxyFieldValueFactory.html

Quote: "This class will also cache any produced proxies so that the same proxy is always returned for the same spring dependency." This explains why wicket uses 'old beans' even though the Spring Context is refreshed. 

This class is used by the SpringComponentInjector. As such, we do not wish to change how this works as doing so would result in a heavy impact on our production code (not caching beans in production would be bad).